# How do I set up MySQL table for this contentEditable

Tags: mysql, contenteditable

I have set up the database correctly I believe because the webpage doesn't return that error, but I don't know how to create the table in the database so this code can save to the database and then retrieve it.

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $("#save").click(function (e) {         
            var content = $('#editable').html();    

            $.ajax({
                url: 'save.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {
                content: content
                },              
                success:function (data) {

                    if (data == '1')
                    {
                        $("#status")
                        .addClass("success")
                        .html("Data saved successfully")
                        .fadeIn('fast')
                        .delay(3000)
                        .fadeOut('slow');   
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $("#status")
                        .addClass("error")
                        .html("An error occured, the data could not be saved")
                        .fadeIn('fast')
                        .delay(3000)
                        .fadeOut('slow');   
                    }
                }
            });   

        });

        $("#editable").click(function (e) {
            $("#save").show();
            e.stopPropagation();
        });

        $(document).click(function() {
            $("#save").hide();  
        });

    });

</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrap">
        <h1><a href="http://gazpo.com/2011/09/contenteditable/" > HTML5 Inline text editing and saving </a></h1>

        <h4>The demo to edit the data with html5 <i>contentEditable</i>, and saving the changes to database with PHP and jQuery.</h4>

        <div id="status"></div>

        <div id="content">

        <div id="editable" contentEditable="true">
        <?php
            //get data from database.
            include("db.php");
            $sql = mysql_query("select text from content where element_id='1'");
            $row = mysql_fetch_array($sql);         
            echo $row['text'];
        ?>      
        </div>  

        <button id="save">Save</button>
        </div>

        <div id="footer">
        <a href="http://gazpo.com/">Tutorial by gazpo.com</a> 
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Please, **DO NOT** use the creaky, antiquated, soon to be removed from PHP entirely `mysql_query` in new applications. What reference are you using that advised you to do this?

Comment: Like @tadman said, don't use mysql_* anything. Look into PDO or MySQLi. Also, you haven't shown us what save.php does. You're just showing us your jQuery, which accesses save.php. Do you need someone to create all of the pages for you?

Comment: I was following this tutorial, http://gazpo.com/2011/09/contenteditable/, what I am trying to do is create a family directory where people are able to edit their info and everybody can see those edits. Is there an easier way to do this. I wouldn't think it would have to be secure because I will just put a password over the whole page and give that to family members.

Comment: You'd probably do a lot better with a popular [PHP framework](http://www.phpframeworks.com/top-10-php-frameworks/) because it will give you a foundation to build off of rather than having to rely on tutorials like that full of outdated if not simply bad practices. It takes a little longer to learn how to use a framework effectively, but you can be considerably more productive with one. You should not be using `mysql_query`, it's being removed from PHP completely, so learning it is a complete waste of time and will just mean you'll have to rewrite all your MySQL interfacing code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not arguing with the commenting folks above about the usefulness of the tutorial, but if you want to create the necessary tables just to finish this, you might issue the following two SQL statements:

```
CREATE TABLE content ( element_id varchar(1), text text);
INSERT INTO content (element_id, text) VALUES ('1','Hello World!');
```

This table will not be much useful for anything else, however.

Um, which database? I guess you first have to create one, but the name of the database (and the user / password needed to connect to it) are not visible in the code snippets. I guess they are somewhere hidden in the `db.php`. If you are using exactly the downloaded example from the tutorial, issue the following statements before the ones above:

```
CREATE DATABASE test;
use test
```

(Oh, and this tutorial assumes you can login with the `root` account without password - if you have set up your mySQL DB that way, I hope you have a firewall running on your development server.)

Comment: thank you that worked, I appreciate everyone's help. I am pretty good with html and css, and just barely starting to get into js. So I have no idea what I am doing with all this php stuff, do you have any recommendations for how to do this better?

Comment: Actually I am a complete php noop, but know a little about mySQL ;) I see tadman e.g. linked to some php frameworks; they usually have a tutorial too. Check then out and see if there is one you understand. CakePHP e.g. has one creating a complete blog ... I just read it because I liked the name, no idea about the quality. Finally there are the PHP reference docs at http://www.php.net/manual/en/ , useful if you want to know e.g. what the heck function `strpbrk` does. It also tells you which functions are deprecated. (And it has a four page simple tutorial all without js and databases ...)